# Oracle SQl- How to Convert T00:00:00 into AM or PM readable time in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime, time

I tried to convert via:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP ("T00:00:00", '"T"hh:mi:ss')
```

It displayed error>>

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
> the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
> "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
> with no extra whitespace.
> *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Comment: Which result are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate issue is with `hh`: this stands for a 12-hour based format (am/pm), so it allows values between `1` and `12` only (`0` is not a valid hour in 12-hour format).

You also should not be using double quotes around the literal string ; but I don't think you are actually doing that in your code, otherwise you would get error `invalid identifier`.

Then: there is no `time` datatype in Oracle anyway - just `date` (which, couter-intuitively enough, includes a time portion), and various flavors of `timestamp`s. If you are looking to convert the input string to a string that represents a `time` in AM/PM format, then you can do something like this:

```
to_char(to_date('T00:00:00', '"T"hh24:mi:ss'), 'hh12:mi:ss am')
```

This turns the time string to a `date` (the date part defaults to the current date when not specified), then returns its time portion format in am/pm format. This yields:

```
12:00:00 AM
```